# How to import a CSV data to a single list and append some values to the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My code:

```
import os
import csv
mylist = []
data = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'filename.csv'
with open(data, 'r') as file:
  read = csv.reader(file)
  mylist = list(read)
print(mylist)
mylist.append('hello')
print(mylist)
```

When printing, the output shows:

```
[['25', '50', '33', '24', '214', '1587']]
[['25', '50', '33', '24', '214', '1587'], 'hello']
```

Importing CSV data is loading as a list inside a list. But I need the same in a single list that I can later append some values like 'hello' in the same list.

Example: (I need the same like)

```
['25', '50', '33', '24', '214', '1587', 'hello']
```

please provide a fix:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `chain.from_iterables` from `itertools`:

```
import itertools

mylist = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
mylist = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
mylist.append('hello')
```

```
>>> mylist
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

Output before and after appending:

```
['25', '50', '33', '24', '214', '1587']
['25', '50', '33', '24', '214', '1587', 'hello']
```

Code:

```
import os
import csv
mylist = []
data = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'filename.csv'
with open(data, 'r') as file:
  read = csv.reader(file)
  mylist = list(read)
print(mylist)
y=[]
for x in range(len(mylist)):
    y.append(mylist[x])
mylist = y
mylist.append('hello')
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import os
import csv
mylist = []
data = os.getcwd() + '/' + 'filename.csv'
with open(data, 'r') as file:
  read = csv.reader(file)
  mylist = list(read)
print(mylist)
mylist2 = mylist[0]
mylist2.append('hello')
print(mylist2)
```

Where `mylist2 = mylist[0]` assumes your list from reading the csv file is 1-level nested list. Then, you can append new value to your new list `mylist2`